# Как обойти защиту от ботов, используя python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, requests, urllib

Мне нужно получить некоторую информацию с [этой страницы](http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-rent?sort=date&order=desc&limit=20&market=residential):

Но сайт перемещает меня на страницу бота после нескольких обращений к странице.

Я использую следующий код:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-rent?sort=date&order=desc&limit=20&market=residential'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Напомню, что вы попали на Stackoverflow на русском.

Comment: I am able to get page by copying the cookies from the browser into headers. And then, after 3-4 times they stop working

Comment: @Юра Любченко In this resource, it is customary to ask and answer questions in Russian. Ask a question in Russian, or go to the English version of the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в запрос больше хедеров которые отправляет сам браузер, 
чтоб более качественно его сымитировать (например `referer`, `connection`).

Еще на сайте может стоять ограничение на количество запросов за определенное время с одного IP адреса. Попробуйте делать запросы, например, не больше одного за 5 секунд.

Comment: 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Connection': 'close',
'Host': 'www.propertyguru.com.sg',
'Referer': 'http://www.propertyguru.com.sg/singapore-property-listing/property-for-rent?sort=date&order=desc&limit=20&market=residential',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'

Comment: Раза 3-4 работает, потом опять в заглушку кидает.

Comment: Возможно на сайте стоит ограничение на количество запросов за определенное время с одного IP адреса. Попробуйте делать запросы, например, не больше одного за 5 секунд.

Comment: Да, вы оказались правы, решил проблему сохраняя сессию с сервером.
 `with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get(url)`